# In the typescript, the reflect-metadata package does not work properly

Tags: typescript

I used the `reflect-metadata` installation package, I introduced it, and configured some corresponding methods in the tsconfig file, I have to specify some parameters:

Must be specified: `moduleResolution: node`

`tsconfig.js:`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "declaration": true,
    "typeRoots": ["@/types"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Specify the parameter as node to use normally, otherwise it will report an error,
**`Reflect.defineMetadata is not a function`**

```
import 'reflect-metadata'

function f (target: any) {
  return function (target: string, propertyKey: any, descriptor) {
    Reflect.defineMetadata('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')
  }
}

class Person {
 @f()
 move () {}
}
```

**I just used this method of defineMetadata and didn't do anything, but webpack won't automatically load it, and the whole process stops.**

I have to manually force the shutdown and restart `npm run dev`

**How to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way to import `reflect-metadata` into TypeScript has changed over time due to changes in the way the typings are handled, but I think currently you need to do this:

`import * as Reflect from 'reflect-metadata';`

Comment: I tried to introduce it like this, but it didn't work, and I also gave an error.
`Property 'defineMetadata' does not exist on type 'typeof import`

Comment: I guess the simple `import 'reflect-metadata'` really is the way to import this. The module only exports this: `export { };`, then does this: `declare global { namespace Reflect { ...`, because it's doing a polyfill. But I was able to load the module just fine.

Comment: I tried all the methods that might be imported:
`import * as Reflect from 'reflect-metadata'`
and
`import Reflct from 'reflect-metadata'`

or
 it didn't work,

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue. In my case the solution was to add reflect-metadata to dependencies :

```
npm install -D --save reflect-metadata
```